# Auto Update OpenJPA tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, openjpa

Is there a way to tell `OpenJPA` to automatically update tables in the database on application deployment?

I know that hibernate has a property:

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
```

Is there something similar in `OpenJPA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
<property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema"/>
```

http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.2.0/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_conf_jdbc.html#openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings

Sebastian